# Selected Items generic converter to List

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, datagrid

I'm trying to make a generic Converter from DataGrid.SelectedItems to a generic List

```
public class SelectedItemsToListConverter : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGrid dg =  (DataGrid)parameter;  
        Type type = parameter.GetType().MemberType.GetType();

        return dg.SelectedItems.OfType<type.GetType()>().ToList();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the `object` parameter I'm passign the entire `DataGrid`, with hope can get the base type of `ItemsSource`

but when try

```
dg.SelectedItems.OfType<type.GetType()>().ToList();
```

or

```
dg.SelectedItems.OfType<type>().ToList();
```

It doesn´t recognize the type.

How can I do to get the type and pass it to `dg.SelectedItems.OfType<T>`?

There is allready a generic converter to perform this ?

**NOTE:** I need to convert `SelectedItems` to use it as a parameter of `ICommand`, my command expects a `List<T>`, then my converter must convert **SelectedItems** to `List<T>`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CausacionesDisponibles" GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ItemsSource="{Binding CausacionesRealizadasAlTercero}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DetallarCausacionCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CausacionesDisponibles,Path=SelectedItems}" HERE NEED TO USE THE CONVERTER/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StrIdDocumento}" Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.GENERAL_IdDocumeto}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DatFechaDocumento}" Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.GENERAL_FechaDocumento}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StrUsuarioGenera,StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.GENERAL_GeneradoPor}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Check in debugger what is actual type of an item in SelectedItems, is it the same you are expecting to hacve?

Comment: The code doesn't compile. ``can't find the type`` **type** or when use **parameter.GetType().MemberType.GetType()** ``operator < can't ne applied to perands of type methods group or System.Type``

Comment: I don't think [`MemberType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.membertype.aspx) means what you think it means.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like:

```
public class SelectedItemsToListConverter<TIn, TOut> : BaseConverter, IValueConverter where TIn : class where TOut : class
{
    public IEnumerable<TOut> Convert(object value, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGrid dg = parameter as DataGrid;  
        // You might need some conversion logic here
        return dg.SelectedItems.OfType<TIn>();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I might have missunderstood what you are trying to achieve, so take this advice with a grain of salt. Perhaps someone else might have a better idea on how to approach this.

Comment: Tks a lot, but how to use it on XAML?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying, to made a converter for use it with a ICommand on a view,model.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to bind to this Convert method in XAML, try to look at this MSDN reference that points out how to send in method parameters in XAML using XPath: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx I hope this helps.

Comment: Alternatively you might want to encapsulate the method in some type of Command, such as a DelegateCommand available in Prism, where you can specify the arguments based on the values in the ViewModel, to which the View binds to. Typically you take an ObservableCollection or any other Collection type and use them as the data source for the DataGrid, so instead of accessing the DataGrid try working with the collection itself, just an idea.

Comment: tks for your hel, but what I'm reeally need is the ``SelectedItems``, selected by the user in the ``DataGrid``

Comment: You could hook onto the SelectedItemsChanged event and trough it pass the selected items to the ViewModel and work from there with them using the Converter, all you need is an ObservableCollection or an IEnumerable that's public and accessible to the view. And you could do this in the code behind. Also you might want to take a look at this: http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Answer (score 0):

If a `List<object>` is acceptable, you can simply do:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)parameter;

    return dg.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToList();
}
```

Or if you need to get the type another way, e.g. here I take the type of the first element.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)parameter;
    var itemType = dg.SelectedItems[0].GetType();
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(listType, dg.SelectedItems);
}
```

The last two lines are the reflection version of `return new List<itemType>(dg.SelectedItems);`

If you actually wanted `OfType` behavior, i.e. filtering to items of a specific type, instead of just `Cast`, you can do that too, (`currentItemType.IsAssignableFrom(someTargetType)`) but your example didn't appear to need that.